# How do I change the color of one cell (N5) based on the two other cells "is not empty" (C5&D5)

Tags: google-sheets

What formula would I use in Google Sheets if I want a cell(total dose, N5) to turn red if Cell C5 and Cell D5 are no longer blank? or "is not empty"

For example, I want N5 to turn red when C5 & D5 have numbers added to them (or are no longer empty).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To color cell `N5` when there is a value in cell `C5` *and* cell `D5`, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule:

```
=len(C5) * len(D5)
```

To color cell `N5` when there is a value in cell `C5` *or* cell `D5` *or* both, use this:

```
=len(C5) + len(D5)
```